# getting mongodb entries with mongoose, fires wrong route, returns everything

Tags: regex, angular, mongodb, mongoose

I have been trying to implement a search function on my website but I keep failing.

I am testing the API with Postman but the code below always returns everything there is - regardeless of the conditions I set. Can someone explain to me what my mistake is?

I've seen the other questions here about text-search but the answers match my code - at least as far as I can see.

**the controller code:**

```
const db = require("../models");
const IndexArticle = db.article_index;

exports.findAllContaining = (req, res) => {
const term = req.params.term;
const headline = req.query.headline;  
var condition =  { headline: { $regex: new RegExp(/.+term.+/), $options: "i" } };
IndexArticle.findAll(condition)
.sort({ $natural: -1 }).limit(50)

  .then(data => {
    res.send(data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({
      message:
        err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving index_articles."
    });
  });
```

};

**and this is the route**

```
var router = require("express").Router();

//retrieve all published articles containing term
router.get("/?search=:term", article_index.findAllContaining);
```

I am new to working with the back-end and appreciate any advice.

**the model file:**

```
module.exports = mongoose => {
const IndexArticle = mongoose.model(
  "indexArticle",
  mongoose.Schema(
    {
      headline: String,
      timestamp: String,
      tags: [String],
      region: String,
      proof: Array,
      sources: Array,
      published: Boolean,

  },
    { timestamps: true }
  )
);

return IndexArticle;
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is wrong. change it to :

```
var condition =  { headline: { $regex: new RegExp(`${term}`), $options: "i" } };
```

And also change `IndexArticle.findAll(condition)` to `IndexArticle.find(condition)`.

(your own regex is `/.+term.+/` which means : at least one character, then the word term, then at least another character. like: `atermb` or `a term a`. )

Comment: @unkn0wn.a there was a small problem in answer, updated it.

Comment: thank you for your help. however, I still have the same issue going on. The request 
`http://localhost:8080/api/article_index/?search=parsing` still returns all the elements I have in my database - for example this one: `{
        "tags": [
            "[Karelle,Janet91,Waelchi]"
        ],
        "region": "Tuvalu",  "headline": "I'll calculate the wireless EXE bus, that should array the USB alarm!",
        "published": false,
        "createdAt": "2020-08-22T10:12:40.854Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-08-22T10:12:40.854Z",
        "__v": 0, 
    }`

Comment: @unkn0wn.a that problem (returning all elements) is most probably not about regx. did you changed: `IndexArticle.findAll` to : `IndexArticle.find` ? if so, the problem is probably inside your `IndexArticle` model. can you share the `models` file?

Comment: @unkn0wn.a there is another possible senario: you have a root route that is fired instead of this route. check if the route is firing with : `exports.findAllContaining = (req, res) => {return res.send({hey: 'hey'});...}`

Comment: okay, so it seems like the route is not firing - with the res.send it still returns all the elements - I'll add the model to the post above  - How can I fix this?

Comment: @unkn0wn.a forget about the model.(looking into your model, i confirmed that you should use `find` instead of `findAll`.) if the route is not firing, it means that another route is firing. (probably the route you have for all routes.). you should find that route. also note that if you have `router.get("/?search=:term"` and `router.get("/"`, and you want to use second for all and first for search, you can't do it. cause both are same. you can instead use one route for both, or use `router.get("/:term/"` for first one (search).

Comment: okay, I got it working now - thank you so much! I changed the route of all to `router.get("/all")`  and the one for search to `router.get("/:term/"`

Comment: @unkn0wn.a No problem. i think it's more standatd to name them like: `router.get("/")` for all and `router.get("/:term/")` for each one.